Remove words in columns in pandas DataFrame based on total frequency
I have a dataframe. I want to figure out which words appear exactly five times in the whole corups. I also need to figure out how to remove all of those words from the dataframe/remove the columns.
I used this code
df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('_y')],axis=1,inplace=True)
to drop any that ended with y but I don't know how to adjust the code to find words that come up exactly equal to 5.

Be explicit, provide a [mre] of the input DataFrame and the matching expected output. Your question is too ambiguous to answer without more details.

Lets say you have a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I have used this dummy example:
data = {
    'apple': [1, 2, 1],        # Total: 4
    'banana': [2, 1, 2],       # Total: 5
    'cherry': [0, 0, 0],       # Total: 0
    'date': [5, 0, 0],         # Total: 5
    'elderberry': [3, 2, 1]    # Total: 6
}

First, calculate the total frequency per word.
word_counts = df.sum(axis=0)

Second, identify words with exactly five occurances:
words_to_remove = word_counts[word_counts == 5].index.tolist()

Thirdly, remove the identiifed columns from the dataframe:
df.drop(columns=words_to_remove, inplace=True)

Print output from my own script:
Original DataFrame:
   apple  banana  cherry  date  elderberry
0      1       2       0     5           3
1      2       1       0     0           2
2      1       2       0     0           1

Total frequency of each word:
apple         4
banana        5
cherry        0
date          5
elderberry    6
dtype: int64

Words to remove (frequency == 5): ['banana', 'date']

DataFrame after removing words with frequency exactly 5:
   apple  cherry  elderberry
0      1       0           3
1      2       0           2
2      1       0           1


Assuming words are separated by spaces in your column names...

Combine all your column names into a single string and then use count words using str.split() and Counter.
List words with a strict count of 5
Create regex of bad words by joining list with '|'
Identify columns with df.columns.str.contains using regex pattern
Drop columns


from collections import Counter
# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["hello", "hello world", "hello goodbye", "hello hello", "foo", "foo foo foo foo foo"])

word_count = Counter(' '.join(df.columns).split())

remove_words = [word for word in word_count if word_count[word] == 5]

columns_to_drop = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(remove_words))]

df.drop(columns = columns_to_drop)

